# ForestDNSZone vs DomainDNSZones

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I've noticed that I am getting Event ID 4515 events in my logs and using ADSIedit have determined that I have duplicate entries in my DNS for my domains.

In the article found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/867464) it is recommended that you pick either ForestDNSzone or DomainDNSzone as the main replication location and delete the entries in the other.

I am running a 2008R2 forest with all 2008R2 DCs with one root domain and one child.  One thing that I cannot determine is which is the better choice: Forest zone or Domain zone?  Based on my reading it appears the DomainDNSZone is the better spot but I want to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third option is the Windows 2000 compatibility mode, where it stores the zones in the main AD container.. but this obviously isn't something you're interested in doing.

What's best depends pretty heavily on your network's architecture and your DNS forwarding layout.  There's no drawback to using Forest, other than the increase in replication load (still very light), but you'll want to lay things out in a way that makes sense and is clean and easy to manage.

For the domain zones, AD's default is the way to be.  The `_msdcs` zone gets put in ForestDNSZones, and each domain's zones get put in DomainDNSZones.

Say, for instance, reverse lookup zones.  If your root and child domains reside on different network segments, then make a separate zone for each and store it in the DomainDNSZones container.  However, if they're sharing subnet(s), store the zone in the Forest container.

For something like a zone unrelated to your namespace that you want to hit with internal clients, just pick wherever's easiest.  The one thing I'll advise you not to do is have two copies of the same zone in the different levels of the domain.. that's not fun.

Comment: I do have copies in both at this point and that is why I am getting all these errors.   My two domains are on different subnets, so it sounds like DomainDNSZone is the way to go.   Everything is in the same name space.